# Bootstrap columns stacking vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

```css
.card {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(238, 185, 80);
}

.box3 {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: rgb(137, 137, 235);
}

.box5 {
  background-color: rosybrown;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: sienna;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row card mx-auto">
    <div class=" col-4 box box1">BOX1</div>
    <div class=" col-4 box box2">BOX2</div>
    <div class=" col-4 box box3">BOX3</div>
    <div class=" col box box4">BOX4</div>
    <div class=" col box box5">BOX5</div>
    <div class=" col box box6">BOX6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to use the bootstrap grid to create a grid however the columns are stacking vertically instead of horizontally. I am trying to achieve a grid like on the picture:

[image: grid-photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the class `card`.

`card` is a builtin class name for bootstrap which aligns the items inside of it vertically.

You can simply rename the class `card` to anything else like `card2` and it will work.

Working Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/es318vm7/1/

```css
.card2 {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(238, 185, 80);
}

.box3 {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: rgb(137, 137, 235);
}

.box5 {
  background-color: rosybrown;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: sienna;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row card2 mx-auto">
    <div class=" col-4 box box1">BOX1</div>
    <div class=" col-4 box box2">BOX2</div>
    <div class=" col-4 box box3">BOX3</div>
    <div class=" col box box4">BOX4</div>
    <div class=" col box box5">BOX5</div>
    <div class=" col box box6">BOX6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change your container name card to something else

the `.card` class is one of the in-built components of bootstrap which can not be used

Check the fiddle below and adjust your elements as per your requirements.

```css
.card {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  min-height:150px;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(238, 185, 80);
}

.box3 {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: rgb(137, 137, 235);
}

.box5 {
  background-color: rosybrown;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: sienna;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box1">BOX1</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box2">BOX2</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box3">BOX3</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box4">BOX4</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box5">BOX5</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="box box6">BOX6</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```